# Re-installing the bot in teams for the same user, does not call OnMembersAddedAsync() method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have developed a bot to be used in Microsoft Teams, and I use `OnMembersAddedAsync` method to save user details such as **conversation ID** and **AAD ID** so that they can be used later to send proactive messages to the user in MS Teams. In case, even if I loose this details I used to uninstall and re-install the bot through App Studio or by Side loading the app in teams, the bot used to trigger this method and then I get the user details again.

[image: Screenshot of Bot sending multiple welcome message as the bot was re-installed multiple times]

*Caption: Screenshot of Bot sending multiple welcome message as the bot was re-installed multiple times*

Everything was working normal, but since this Monday, 20th July, 2020, the bot seems to have stopped calling that method and due to which now I am unable to get the user details if the user is re-installing the bot.

`OnMembersAddedAsync` method:

```
protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        Logger.LogInfo("In OnMembersAddedAsync.");
        var welcomeText = "Hello and welcome!";
        foreach (var member in membersAdded)
        {
            if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
            {
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(welcomeText, welcomeText), cancellationToken);
            }
        }

        // Logic to save user details
        
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.LogError(ex.Message);
        Logger.LogError(ex.StackTrace);

        if (ex.InnerException != null)
        {
            Logger.LogError("Inner Exception: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
            Logger.LogError("Inner Exception: " + ex.InnerException.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

As of now this method is not even triggered and the first logger line is also not printed.

After doing some research, I have also added, `OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync` method, but even this method is not triggered:

```
protected override Task OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        Logger.LogInfo("In  OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync....");
        return base.OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.LogError(ex.Message);
        Logger.LogError(ex.StackTrace);

        if (ex.InnerException != null)
        {
            Logger.LogError("Inner Exception: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
            Logger.LogError("Inner Exception: " + ex.InnerException.StackTrace);
        }
    }
    return base.OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
}
```

Packages used:

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Core(2.1.1)
Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core(4.7.0)
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue with a node api. After re-install the node api is not being called at all. This started for us Thursday night the 16th. I've contacted their support team describing the issue.

Comment: Seems others are also facing the same issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Services/issues/213)

Comment: Currently, there is an issue going on with Bot events, our team is investigating this internally.

Comment: The fix for this is completed but it might take upto 2 weeks to reach WW. Thanks!

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT Is this change shipped, if yes in which version of the nuget ?